# How to use a value across different widgets?

Tags: flutter

I am new to programming, specifically to Dart and Flutter. I am stuck on a situation where I have created a widget and I need to use the value defined in that widget in another widget.

```
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
    
class DateTimePicker extends StatefulWidget {
  final String title;
  const DateTimePicker({Key key, this.title}) : super(key: key);
  @override
  _DateTimePickerState createState() => _DateTimePickerState();
}

class _DateTimePickerState extends State<DateTimePicker> {
  DateTime selectedDate;

  Future<Null> _selectDate(BuildContext context) async {
    final DateTime picked = await showDatePicker(
        context: context,
        initialDate: selectedDate,
        firstDate: DateTime(2000),
        lastDate: DateTime(2050));
    if (picked != null) {
      setState(() {
        selectedDate = picked;
      });
    }
  }

  @override
  void initState() {
    selectedDate = DateTime.now();
    super.initState();
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Container(
      decoration: BoxDecoration(
        borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(5.0),
        border: Border.all(color: Colors.grey[400]),
      ),
      child: ListTile(
        onTap: () => _selectDate(context),
        leading: Icon(Icons.calendar_today, color: Colors.grey[400]),
        title: Text(
            '${widget.title}\n${selectedDate.year}-${selectedDate.month}-${selectedDate.day}'),
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In Dart you can pass the Function as a Parameter.

1). First Declare a variable on Your Main Widget and create a function to change a value.

2). On the other widgets pass the function and call them to change the value.

**Example is given below**

```
class MainClass extends StatefulWidget {
  MainClass({Key key}) : super(key: key);

  @override
  _MainClassState createState() => _MainClassState();
}

class _MainClassState extends State<MainClass> {
  int value = 0;

  changeValue(int newValue) {
    setState(() {
      value = newValue;
    });
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Container(
      child: Column(
        children: <Widget>[
          InnerClass2(value: value,),
          InnerClass(
            changeValue: changeValue,
          ),
        ],
      ),
    );
  }
}

class InnerClass extends StatefulWidget {
  Function changeValue;

  InnerClass({@required this.changeValue, Key key}) : super(key: key);

  @override
  _InnerClassState createState() => _InnerClassState();
}

class _InnerClassState extends State<InnerClass> {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Container(
      child: RaisedButton(
        onPressed: () {
          widget.changeValue(2);
        },
      ),
    );
  }
}

class InnerClass2 extends StatelessWidget {
   final int value;
  const InnerClass2({@required this.value, Key key}) : super(key: key);

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Container(
      child: Text(value.toString()),
    );
  }
}
```

Comment: thats what I am looking for. Thanks.

Comment: Welcome and if this help you dont forget to accept this answer :)